# Django Admin Form DateTime Field, display in users system-time but save as UTC

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want the users on Django admin form to `see the time in their own local / system time` but store it as `UTC` on the `DB`.
I researched this and got a lot of confusing information, how would you deal with this?

My current settings are:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Postgres 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django admin: timezone display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730230/django-admin-timezone-display). Django automatically saves times entered by the user correctly, as absolute times. The thing is, it doesn't know the timezone of a user, so by default it will display all times in the default timezone (UTC in your case). You have to activate the timezone of the user yourself (and figure a way to get the user's timezone, generally by asking the user to set it themselves in their user preferences).