# Display a timestamp with timezone in Django admin

Tags: django, timezone

I have a model with a timezone-aware `DateTimeField`. Each object may use a different timezone. I'd like Django Admin to display this field with the timezone suffix (`EST`, etc.), not in the user's or server's local time.

I don't want to globally modify my project's timezone localization settings. This should apply only to this one field.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730230/django-admin-timezone-display) touches on something similar, but I am skeptical of the solution; it activates a new timezone when the object class is initialized, which does not allow changing the timezone per-row, and affects other timestamps that are not the particular field I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to replace the `timestamp` field with a computed field where we manually handle the timezone:

```
class EventInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Event
    readonly_fields = ('timestamp_local',)

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super().get_fields(request, obj=obj)
        fields.remove('timestamp_local')
        fields[fields.index('timestamp')] = 'timestamp_local'
        return fields

    def timestamp_local(self, obj):
        d = obj.timestamp
        return (f'{d.strftime("%b")} {d.day}, {d.year} at '
                f'{d.strftime("%H:%M:%S %Z")}')

    timestamp_local.short_description = 'timestamp'
```

I tried using Django's timezone support and `dateformat` utility module but had some trouble. (Are these even used by the rest of Django Admin? Updating `DATETIME_FORMAT` does not change how Admin renders timestamps.)

However it appears that dates are being stored as UTC and the timezone information is lost. I had to store the timezone separately, and use `obj.timestamp.astimezone(pytz.timezone(obj.timestamp_tz))`